# Cambiar ruta de archivos cuando se compila con create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, build

Tengo una aplicacion de ReactJS generada por `create-react-app`. Cuando ejecuto `react-scripts build` me genera una carpeta `build` en cual dentro tengo un `index.html`. Dentro del `index.html` llama los estilos y los scripts de javascript de la siguente manera:

- muestro ejemplos genericos

`/static/js/<script>.js` o `/static/css/<estilo>.css`

Tambien tengo la carga de algunas imagen, o el icono de la app

`/icon.png` o `/logo.png`

El tema que en el servidor, para que me traiga los estilos y los scripts necesito modificar a mano el `index.html`, y le agrego adelante de esas rutas los siguente `/apps/projecto` dejando todas las llamas de la siguente manera:

`/apps/projecto/static/js/<script>.js` o `/apps/projecto/static/js/<script>.js`

`/apps/projecto/icon.png` o `/apps/projecto/logo.png`

Como puedo hacer para que al momento de compilar me genere la ruta que yo quiera? asi no tengo que estar cambiando a mano cada vez que compile el proyecto

Gracias

Comment: ¿Puedes agregar a tu pregunta el contenido de `webpack.config.js`?

Comment: No tengo `webpack.config.js` Cuando ejecuta `npm run build` ejecuta el siguente comando: `react-scripts build`. Ahora edito la pregunta haciendo esa descripcion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes dos opciones para lograr esto. La más sencilla es crear un archivo `.env` en tu proyecto.
A dicho archivo deberás añadirle la siguiente línea de código:

```
# .env
BUILD_PATH='./path/to/desired/build/folder'
```

La otra opción es agregar el siguiente código en la sección de `scripts` de tu archivo `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "BUILD_PATH='./path/to/desired/build/folder' react-scripts build",
  // ...
},
```

Solo asegúrate que el componente `react-scripts` sea parte de tus dependencias en `package-json`.

Comment: Eso lo unico que hizo fue que me genere dentro de mi proyecto una rurta puntual diferente a como se se complica por defecto. Pero dentro de mi index.html sigo teniendo lo que no necesito: Muestro un ejemplo
`<script src="/static/js/main.866d032c.chunk.js"></script>`
y necesito:
`<script src="/apps/totems/static/js/main.866d032c.chunk.js"></script>`

Comment: Y por qué no pones toda esa ruta que necesitas en el BUILD_PATH?

Answer (score 1):

Te comento que logre cambiarlo.

En el archivo index.html después de haber compilado.

En el primer script hace referencia a los archivos css y js, agrega la ruta antes de static sin slash por ejemplo: miruta/static...

Además debes cambiar los ultimos scripts con tu ruta completa.

Saludos.

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/305639)